# AVFoundation concat videos and audio

Tags: swift, html, google-chrome, video, avfoundation

I am trying to concat 2 videos, one after another with AVFoundation framework. When I export with AVAssetExport the result is just fine! 
When I play the video with **HTML5 Video** I can watch it on Safari, Firefox but not on Google Chrome.
After a deep analysis I found out that the root cause is that **the exported video has 2 audio channels**!!!!
Infact if I remove audio from videos everything works also on Google Chrome.

In my code I added the audio in the same track but different time ranges:

```
asset1.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)[0].insertTimeRange(asset1.duration, asset1, start1)
asset2.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)[0].insertTimeRange(asset2.duration, asset2, start2)
```

I guess this produce me 2 separate audiotracks instead of one, which are not allowed on Google Chrome.
At this link you can find the video: http://www.livebomber.com/prova.php
If you open it with Safari or Firefox works fine but with Google Chorome will show an error.
How can I merge all audio tracks into one and export?
thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the very same problem while I'm using [this](https://github.com/mkoehnke/MKOVideoMerge) library to merge 3 videos! 2 of them were from same resource but the other one was from a different resource with different resolution and settings. After digging it for two days, I've founded out that all I needed to do was having the problematic video's audio channel to convert to mono.

I know, it's not a permanent solution using any code but I think it gives an idea to the ones who wants to solve it using code :)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the help. I will definitely try this out.
Just to explain you better, in my case i got 1 video mp4 at 48k audio sample rate and another one mov at 44,1k audio sample rate from iOS camera.
Both are 480x640.
What is the best way to convert stereo to mono?

Comment: Hey Alessio, audio property differences within a merged video clip may be a major risk of playback issues. I’ve used Adobe Premiere to creat the video I was using. A open-source command line tool ‘ffmpeg’ might be used for convertion, too. However I think the best way would be handling all these conversions within the app using AVFoundation but I don’t have enough experience with it, sorry :/

Comment: Thank you so much!! A solution might be to re-encode with AVAssetWriter frame by frame.. but I haven’t tried yet..